# Download doesn't start in web browser by flask.Response

Tags: python, file, stream, flask, python-requests

In Flask (micro web framework), we have a view as:

```
@app.route('/download/<id>/<resolution>/<extension>/')
def download_by_id(id, resolution=None, extension=None):
    stream = youtube.stream_url(id, resolution, extension)
    binary = requests.get(stream['url'], stream=True)
    return flask.Response(
        binary,
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; '
                                        'filename=' + stream['filename']})
```

In template we have a link as `<a href="/download/adkdsk457jds/240p/mp4/">Download 240p Video</a>` and when it's clicked, it should start downloading that video.

Issue is:

It is working fine in some browsers where no Download Manager like IDM etc. is installed. But IDM fails to download it. IDM just hangs at `http://example.com/download/adkdsk457jds/240p/mp4/`

Same is the case with Firefox's own download manager. Firefox just downloads a plain .html page and not the actual video.

But, videos gets downloaded successfully in Chrome when no IDM or other Download Manager is installed.

Please help and advice why it's not working. Do i need to change something in code?

Comment: did you try changing the url so that it ends with `.mp4`?

Comment: by url, you mean changing filename to video1.mp4 or what?

Comment: What your `route` argument and  `href` contains.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski Well, I'm not sure what you mean by href but here `href` is referring to a view of flask which i have show above. So not sure how adding extension would help here?

Comment: A download manager expects to be able to use HTTP-Range requests; Flask is not set up to do ranges. I suspect that that's what is causing the issues here.

Comment: So, how do i resolve it?

Comment: What *headers* does `curl -D - -o /dev/null http://example.com/download/adkdsk457jds/240p/mp4/` produce?

Comment: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Marvels Avengers.mp4
Connection: close
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.6`  I added the `Content-Type` parameter just now

Comment: @CracLock: yes, but if you *had not* added the content type header it'd have said `text/html` as that is the default Flask / Werkzeug sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included any response information, including the content type; you need to copy over a little more information about the original response to communicate what type of response you are returning. Otherwise defaults are used (dictated either by the HTTP standard or by Flask).

Specifically, at the very least you want to copy across the content type, length, and the transfer encoding:

```
headers={
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + stream['filename']
}
for header in ('content-type', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding'):
    if header in binary.headers:
        headers[header] = binary.headers[header]
return flask.Response(binary.raw, headers=headers)
```

I'm using the `response.raw` underlying raw file object; this should work too but has the added advantage that any compression applied by YouTube is retained.

Some download managers may try to use a [HTTP range request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) to grab a download in parallel, even when the server is not advertising that it supports such requests. You should probably respond with a *406 Not Acceptable* response (requesting byte ranges when not supported is a `Accept-*` violation). You'll need to log what headers the download manager sends to be sure if this is the case.

Comment: What is this `response` you're referring to?

Comment: @CracLock: apologies, you named it `binary` in your code.

Comment: and is there any way to determine `file size` and `time` of running, using this `binary`? So that it could be sent in `headers` to caught by download managers.

Comment: @CracLock: `content-length` is the file size; not sure what you mean by *time* here; there is a `date` header you could copy across too.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work with stream's `content-type` which is suppose `video/3gpp` (it just hangs and never starts the download in download manager) but if i exclusively set it to `application/octet-stream` everything works fine. Is there a way to fix it? Something to do with `flask.Response` ?

Comment: @CracLock: the sample stream you are giving is `mp4`; can you give us a sample URL that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @CracLock: and what specific download manager isn't working with that content-type? What are the headers that Flask returns? What are the headers that YouTube gives you?

Comment: headers returned by stream are `{'alternate-protocol': '80:quic,p=0.01', 'content-length': '31340429', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'expires': 'Tue, 27 Jan 2015 11:00:40 GMT', 'server': 'gvs 1.0', 'last-modified': 'Tue, 04 Nov 2014 02:50:02 GMT', 'connection': 'close', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=21299', 'date': 'Tue, 27 Jan 2015 11:00:40 GMT', 'content-type': 'video/mp4'}` note that content-type i sometimes `'video/3gpp` or `'video/x-flv'` as well

Comment: What difference does `binary.raw` vs `binary` makes in `return flask.Response`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69660/discussion-between-craclock-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'` to headers

Comment: I just gave you a hint since you mentioned "Firefox just downloads a plain .html page". And I suppose http-range should always be coupled with content-type.

Comment: Well, for me it worked like charm. :-) Just adding this to headers makes the Download Managers catch the file properly. But still Download Manager's `time left` `file size` is missing, what needs to done for that?

Comment: No, HTTP Range is applicable to any mimetype. Acrobat Reader uses it extensively to load specific pages early, for example. Video players use it when you skip ahead past the section of the video that has already been buffered. And download managers use it to download different parts in videos in parallel.

Comment: But blindly setting the content type to `application/octet-stream` is rather the wrong thing to do when you have the *correct* content type on the response from YouTube?

Comment: Generally make it downloadable is the right thing to do.